# Angular HttpClient Interceptor : Refresh auth token

Tags: angular, authentication, httpclient, refresh-token

Here is my interceptor code

```
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
      constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const userInfo = this.auth.getAuthToken();
        const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + userInfo.access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
        return next.handle(authReq)
          .pipe(catchError( err => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              if (err.status === 401) { debugger;
                console.log('this should print your error!', err.error);
              }
            }
          }));
      }
    }
```

I am getting following error

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
```

I would like to know if there is a fix for this issue ? I want to implement refresh token functionality in http interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const userInfo = this.auth.getAuthToken();
    const authReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + userInfo.access_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });

    //   return next.handle(authReq)
    //     .pipe(catchError( err => {
    //       if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    //         if (err.status === 401) { debugger;
    //           console.log('this should print your error!', err.error);
    //         }
    //       }
    //     }));

    return next.handle(authReq).do(
      (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          // do stuff with response if you want
        }

      },
      (err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            console.log("this should print your error!", err.error);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```